# Extending my program with another while loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Firstly, i'm very new to java, so excuse the mess of the code below.

My current program takes input from StdIn and prints out the highest and lowest values entered.

Can this be extended to ask the useר again if they entered an integer that isn't positive? I'm almost certain that a while loop can do the trick, but not sure if one executed with my current code. Once again, i'm very new and come from a music background, so my logical sense isn't the best.

```
public class PositiveIntegers
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

do {
   StdOut.println("Enter your integers:");
} while (StdIn.isEmpty());

int max = StdIn.readInt();
int min = max;

while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
int value = StdIn.readInt();
if (value > max) max = value;
if (value < min) min = value;
}

do {
  StdOut.println("Maximum = " + max + ", Minimum = " + min);
  return;
} while (StdIn.readInt() > 0);


  }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: your code is really a mess and your question is not at all clear

Comment: @Ravi As mentioned, i'm quite aware that the code is a mess. Two other users managed to understand the question, so i'm not sure what you're getting out of that comment. I hope that you're aware that some of us StackOverflow users are new to the realm programming (and anything related to the topic for that matter), so maybe have some patience with us? If you're going to comment on anything that doesn't provide anything constructive, then don't comment at all.

Comment: Seriously man ???? You look so arrogant when I commented. First of all, it's not about mess, it's about compiled code. I never saw anything similar to`StdOut` and `StdIn` and I can't pretend. You should be at least posting compiled code, so that we can reproduce the error or logic. Now, before you comment you should visit [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see what community expect.

Comment: Also, It doesn't mean, if one person make out something, than everyone should make out. You should ask what was not clear instead of writing long comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by just adding a single if statement to check if the number given is negative, then print the message to add it again.

**Check the ENHANCED code below:**

```
public class PositiveIntegers
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 

   StdOut.println("Enter your integers:");

   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

   while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {

      int value = StdIn.readInt();

      // Adding the if-statement here to check if number is negative.
      if(value < 0){
         StdOut.println("You entered negative number, try positive numbers.");
         // just reset the max and min variables..
         max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
         min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         continue;
      }

      if (value > max) max = value;
      if (value < min) min = value; 
   }

   StdOut.println("Maximum = " + max + ", Minimum = " + min);

   }
}
```

Comment: By the way, i don't know why you use StdIn for input and StdOut for output, may be you create a class for input and output, i make the program accordingly. :)

Comment: That did the trick and cut out a lot of unnecessary code. Thanks a lot! I had no idea the Continue keyword existed! That helps me out a lot, cheers mate!

Comment: @JabroniPepperoni Welcome bro. :)

Comment: Hi there, just playing with out code, but this happens.   Enter your integers:
-1 2
You entered negative number, try positive numbers.
4 5 6
Maximum = 6, Minimum = 2        Any idea my this might happen? As once i input new values, i don't want it to take in the first set of values in account. Cheers

Comment: Can you please explain it more? i don't get what do you want to say.

Comment: Once i enter negative numbers, i get the error message 'You entered negative number, try positive numbers'. So input the correct positive numbers, and i get the highest number from that set of values, but also the highest value from the first set values i entered initially?

Comment: Okay got it, means if user enter's the negative value, then it skip/clean the previous values and start with the new values which you enter. right?

Comment: Yes mate, thats exactly what i mean!

Comment: I edited the code. you just need to reset the max and min variables when any negative number hit, so that it can skip the previous numbers. :) I need upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need this many loops in your program. Take the user input in while loop and then print that number outside of loop.

Remember to use try-catch for error handling for user input.

Try this way :

```
try{
       do {
            StdOut.println("Enter your integers:");
       } while (StdIn.isEmpty() && StdIn.readInt() < 0);
}catch(Exception ex){
      StdOut.println("Error while taking user input !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer to this would be

```
public class PositiveIntegers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        do {
            StdOut.println("Enter your integers:");
        } while (StdIn.isEmpty());

        int max = StdIn.readInt();
        int min = max;

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int value = StdIn.readInt();
            if (value < 0) {
                StdOut.println("Please enter a positive integer");
            } else {
                if (value > max) max = value;
                if (value < min) min = value;
            }
        }

        do {
            StdOut.println("Maximum = " + max + ", Minimum = " + min);
            return;
        } while (StdIn.readInt() > 0);


    }
}
```

I made sure to change as little as possible, but this should give you the result you are looking for.